# Add checkbox control to header of the gridview programmatically

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net, gridview, checkbox

I have created a webform which imports the excel file into gridview.
Now I want to add checkbox control to each header (along with the header text).

Below is the code where I am 
**1. Importing the excel data. 
2. Store it into a datatable 
3. Creating gridview dynamically 
4. Binding the data into the gridview.**

```
    Protected Sub btnUpload_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
    If FileUpload1.HasFile Then
        Dim FileName As String = Path.GetFileName(FileUpload1.PostedFile.FileName)
        Dim Extension As String = Path.GetExtension(FileUpload1.PostedFile.FileName)
        Dim FolderPath As String = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings("FolderPath")

        Dim FilePath As String = Server.MapPath(FolderPath + FileName)
        FileUpload1.SaveAs(FilePath)
        Import_To_Grid(FilePath, Extension, rbHDR.SelectedItem.Text)
    End If
End Sub

    Private Sub Import_To_Grid(ByVal FilePath As String, ByVal Extension As String, ByVal isHDR As String)
    Dim conStr As String = ""
    Select Case Extension
        Case ".xls"

            conStr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("Excel03ConString").ConnectionString
            Exit Select
        Case ".xlsx"

            conStr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("Excel07ConString").ConnectionString
            Exit Select
    End Select
    conStr = String.Format(conStr, FilePath, isHDR)

    Dim connExcel As New OleDbConnection(conStr)
    Dim cmdExcel As New OleDbCommand()
    Dim oda As New OleDbDataAdapter()
    Dim dt As New DataTable()

    cmdExcel.Connection = connExcel


    connExcel.Open()
    Dim dtExcelSchema As DataTable
    dtExcelSchema = connExcel.GetOleDbSchemaTable(OleDbSchemaGuid.Tables, Nothing)
    Dim SheetName As String = dtExcelSchema.Rows(0)("TABLE_NAME").ToString()
    connExcel.Close()


    connExcel.Open()
    cmdExcel.CommandText = "SELECT * From [" & SheetName & "]"
    oda.SelectCommand = cmdExcel
    oda.Fill(dt)
    connExcel.Close()


    Dim GridView1 As GridView = New GridView
    GridView1.AutoGenerateColumns = False
    For i As Integer = 0 To dt.Columns.Count - 1
        Dim boundfield As BoundField = New BoundField

        boundfield.DataField = dt.Columns(i).ColumnName.ToString()
        boundfield.HeaderText = dt.Columns(i).ColumnName.ToString()

        GridView1.Columns.Add(boundfield)
    Next


    GridView1.DataSource = dt
    GridView1.DataBind()
    Panel1.Controls.Add(GridView1)
End Sub
```

All working fine. But when it comes to adding checkbox to header text, I am completely blank. Kindly suggest the solution or any other approach I can use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No Comments :(

Anyway, I have done it myself. It was pretty simple. I was thinking too much. Here's the code.

ASPX:

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>  

        Import Excel File:  
        <asp:FileUpload ID="FileUpload1" runat="server" />
<asp:Button ID="btnUpload" runat="server" Text="Upload"
            OnClick="btnUpload_Click" />
<br />
<asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="Has Header ?" />
<asp:RadioButtonList ID="rbHDR" runat="server">
    <asp:ListItem Text = "Yes" Value = "Yes" Selected = "True" >
    </asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Text = "No" Value = "No"></asp:ListItem>
</asp:RadioButtonList>
        <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server"></asp:GridView>


    </div> 
    </form>
```

Codebehind:

```
Private Sub Import_To_Grid(ByVal FilePath As String, ByVal Extension As String, ByVal isHDR As String)
    Dim conStr As String = ""
    Select Case Extension
        Case ".xls"
            'Excel 97-03
            conStr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("Excel03ConString") _
                       .ConnectionString
            Exit Select
        Case ".xlsx"
            'Excel 07
            conStr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("Excel07ConString") _
                      .ConnectionString
            Exit Select
    End Select
    conStr = String.Format(conStr, FilePath, isHDR)

    Dim connExcel As New OleDbConnection(conStr)
    Dim cmdExcel As New OleDbCommand()
    Dim oda As New OleDbDataAdapter()
    Dim dt As New DataTable()

    cmdExcel.Connection = connExcel


    connExcel.Open()
    Dim dtExcelSchema As DataTable
    dtExcelSchema = connExcel.GetOleDbSchemaTable(OleDbSchemaGuid.Tables, Nothing)
    Dim SheetName As String = dtExcelSchema.Rows(0)("TABLE_NAME").ToString()
    connExcel.Close()


    connExcel.Open()
    cmdExcel.CommandText = "SELECT * From [" & SheetName & "]"
    oda.SelectCommand = cmdExcel
    oda.Fill(dt)
    connExcel.Close()



    GridView1.DataSource = dt
    GridView1.DataBind()

End Sub

Protected Sub GridView1_RowCreated(sender As Object, e As GridViewRowEventArgs) Handles GridView1.RowCreated
    ' Check the header type
    If e.Row.RowType = DataControlRowType.Header Then
        Dim litHeader As Literal
        Dim txtSearch As CheckBox


        ' loop through each cell
        For i As Integer = 0 To (e.Row.Cells.Count - 1)
            litHeader = New Literal
            txtSearch = New CheckBox


            ' get the current header text
            litHeader.Text = e.Row.Cells(i).Text & "&nbsp;"


            ' add the header text plus a new textbox
            e.Row.Cells(i).Controls.Add(txtSearch)
            e.Row.Cells(i).Controls.Add(litHeader)

        Next


    End If
End Sub
```